# Hide/Show Columns using jquery

Tags: jquery

Been looking for a possible solution but I did not find any related to my question.

I have 2 radio buttons and I would like to hide/show the 2nd column of a table which should result to hiding all the Agent Name part

My code:

html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Agent ID</td>
    <td>Agent Name</td>
    <td>UserID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Agent ID</td>
    <td>Agent Name</td>
    <td>UserID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Agent ID</td>
    <td>Agent Name</td>
    <td>UserID</td>        
</tr>
</table>Agent Name OFF<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="hyoujiSentakushi" value="off">&nbspON<input type="radio" name="hyoujiSentakushi" value="on">
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
   $('#hyoujiSentakushi').change(function() {
       $('td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
   });
});
```

On selecting either of the radiobuttons, the code seems lacking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name=hyoujiSentakushi]').change(function () {
        $('tr:nth-child(2) td').toggle(this.value == "on");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PNLDB/)**

Comment: thank you  but what happened is the 2nd row got hide, sorry, my fault also on giving code, I updated the code for table

Comment: Thank you, I figured out with 'td:nth-child.. your solution made it clear to me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selector to bind change event with.
You need name value attribute selector to target those radio button.
try this:

```
 $('[name=hyoujiSentakushi]').change(function() {
  $('td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id or class for the radio button

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" class="rd" name="hyoujiSentakushi" value="off">&nbspON<input type="radio" class="rd" name="hyoujiSentakushi" value="on">
```

.

```
$('.rd').change(function() {
  $('td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
 });
```

or  use @Milind Anantwar's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492200/2967572 that selects the container with name attribute..!!

Comment: I appreciate your help but both of your suggestions arent working, maybe my table pagination with jquery conflicts with this? i try putting it on comment but still dont work